# Try and Catch in phpmailer

Tags: php, jquery, post, echo, phpmailer

I have an html form. When the user press `sumbit` jQuery send a post to a php script (**send.php**) with the data. 
In the **send.php** file I create a php object:

```
 $mail = new PHPMailer(true);
```

Then I do a try and catch:

```
    try {
    $mail->IsSMTP();

    // ........ code for host, usr/psw, body, header ........


    $mail->Send();

    echo "Ok, Sent!\n";

    } catch (phpmailerException $e) {
      echo $e->errorMessage(); 
    }
```

It send me the mail, but I don't know where is the message `echo "Ok, Sent!\n";` ... where is it? I can't see it anywhere. Where should it be? I would like to be shown under the submit `button` , for example it could show this if the input is not correct:

> incorrect data

this if it is sending the email

> sending mail

this if it is correctly sent:

> Ok, Sent!

How can I do?

**UPDATE**
This is the jQuery code in the index.html page:

```
    $('form').submit(function() { 

    var event_data  = encodeURIComponent( $("#event").text() );

    var  formID = $(this).attr('id');
    var formDetails = $('#'+formID);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'send.php', 
        data: formDetails.serialize() + "&event=" + event_data,
        success: function (data) {   
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, text, error){ 
            $('#result').html(error);           
    }
}); 
    return false;
});
```

Comment: it is on the same page `send.php`, please show us your jquery code

Comment: I've posted an answer please see to it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your AJAX code to something like this:

```
$('form').submit(function() { 

    var event_data  = encodeURIComponent( $("#event").text() );

    var  formID = $(this).attr('id');
    var formDetails = $('#'+formID);
    $('#result').html('sending...'); // changing the text before sending mail...
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'send.php', 
        data: formDetails.serialize() + "&event=" + event_data,
        success: function (data) {   
            $('#result').html(data); // this will show the output of the page send.php
            console.log(data); //this will also show the output of the page in the browser console.
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, text, error){ 
            $('#result').html(error);           
    }
}); 
    return false;
});
```

and **send.php** like this:

```
try {
    $mail->IsSMTP();

// ........ code for host, usr/psw, body, header ........


if($mail->Send()){
    echo "Ok, Sent!\n";
}

} catch (phpmailerException $e) {
  echo $e->errorMessage(); 
}
```

Comment: I've added a <div id="result"></div> after the sumbit button. And I've update my code with your editing. But it shows me the "ok, sent!" just in console and not in the html page

Comment: ps: i wrote $('#results').html(data); instead of alert

Comment: Have you added two div's with same `id` as `result`? if so then it wouldn't work...

Comment: No.. I just added a plus more char to the id so I had 2 different Id lol now it works! But now I have two questions: how can I write "sending" while it is sending the email? Is it possible to change the class to the div #result, maybe using jquery add/remove class?

Comment: S U P E R. Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 1):

If you're calling this from a jQuery ajax request, it will be in the response body that jQuery receives, which will be visible in the inspector / dev console of your browser.

Comment: Correct, your 'OK' response will be in the "data" parameter of success function.